# I have a total of two errors, return outside function as well as error with defining variables

Tags: python-3.x, loops, return

I am having trouble with coding this as i am quite new, my code is supposed to take data, return average, as well as make a chart for the information and plot the peaks/valleys of the data

I don't know why it isn't returning and that fault is what makes the code faulty towards the end, the only part that shows error is the code that is supposed to find the peaks/valley values of my code. It also shows invalid syntax when I try to develop a variable (more specifically 'original_data')

EDIT: Thanks to Jono and Ken, I have fixed some of my code, but I checked the values of my lists and they only have one value stored in each, so its not printing all the peaks/valleys of the dataset i had. I getting KeyError: -331 and i can't find results as to how to fix it

```
# My Favorite Function
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()

#import modules
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#key variables
data_set = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/sanderj/Documents/Work/Work_Experience/Day4.csv')
data = data_set["Data"]
peaks = []
valleys = []

#loop functions
for x in data:
    if data[x] == data[0] and data[x] > data[x+1]:
        peaks.append(x)
    elif data[x] > data[x+1] and data[x] > data[x-1]:
        peaks.append(x)
    else:
        continue

for x in data:
    if data[x] == data[0] and data[x] < data[x+1]:
        valleys.append(x)
    elif data[x] < data[x+1] and data[x] < data[x-1]:
        valleys.append(x)
    else:
        continue


#establishing points
a = peaks
b = valleys
plt.plot(a, b, 'ro')
plt.axis([ 0, 1024, -1000, 1000])
plt.title("Peaks and Valleys")

#final
clear()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Instead of using `return` in your for loop (`return` is used with functions), use `break` (ends the loop) or `continue` (goes to the next iteration of the loop).

Comment: It's not returning because it has not gone anywhere and has nowhere to return. The error message is very clear, and tells you clearly what the problem is and what you need to do to fix it. *Return outside function* tells you that you can't use return from anywhere but within a function, and as you don't have a single function in your code the solution would be to write functions from which you can return, or to figure out what you should be using instead of return.

Comment: The `data` variable used in your `for` loops is uninitialized. Where is it coming from?

Comment: @blhsing sorry, just realised, that was supposed to be 'original_data', but i changed it and it still doesn't work

Comment: Thanks Jono 2906 and Ken White, that was helpful, the code has improved although still displays many error messages... I now have one point on my chart.